# Why don't post-deployment scripts run in VS2008 database projects?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008

I've got a VS2008 database project, and I created a post-deployment script under Scripts > Post-Deployment, but it appears to be a no-op (even when I put syntax errors into the file, everything succeeds). The rest of the database deployment succeeds though (and it does create my tables). Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're just placing scripts in your post-deployment directory. You actually need to include them in your `Script.PostDeployment.sql` file. For example:

```
:r .\MyScriptName.sql
:r .\MySecondScript.sql
```

Not every script in the Post-Deployment folder just runs by default; in fact, only one can. By default, it's that `Script.PostDeployment.sql` file. You can change it if you want.

Comment: Yep - figured this out awhile ago but left the question open so someone could get the pts. Such a dumb design.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the question was a little old...sorry about that! Yeah, I totally agree that it's a little bizarre. It'd be nice if there was an option that would just run all the scripts in the folder.